# Attempting to deploy flask app to GAE using gcloud app deploy through Gitlab CI/CD. Logs show ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, gitlab-ci, google-app-engine-python, modulenotfounderror

I have a Flask app which is able to be deployed to my localhost. Unfortunately, when attempting to deploy it to Google App Engine I run into an error. When I follow the link specified in the console after the `gcloud --project $PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml` call in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, I recieve a `500 server error`. To debug this I used the `gcloud app logs read` which show a long error ending with:

```
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed    File 
    "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>      from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, 
    abort  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

My `app.yaml` file reads:

```
entrypoint: "gunicorn -b:$PORT main:app"
service_account: app-engine-admin@###########.iam.gserviceaccount.com
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

my `requirements.txt` reads:

```
firebase_admin==5.2.0
Flask==2.1.2
```

and the called section of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` reads:

```
gcloud-deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - dev2
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud --project $PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml
    - rm /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
```

This error is confusing me as I thought that all libraries listed in the `requirements.txt` file would be imported by GAE during deployment. If someone has run into this or could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try deploying with `gcloud deploy` on the command line and you might get better error messages.  Sharing your directory layout would help. Your requirements.txt might be in the wrong location.

Comment: Theoretically, it means Flask was not installed (even though it' in your requirements.txt file). A common reason for a package not to be installed is because the version specified is in conflict with other dependencies. Is there any reason why you need that specific version of Flask? Can you simply list ```Flask``` without any version or use a different version in your requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this ended up being pretty simple. I was just missing a few packages in the `requirements.txt` file. The main one being the `gunicorn` package. Because it was not installed, the web server was never actually spooled up. This led to the issues I ran into. I solved this by using `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt`.